# Indoor Location without iBeacons

Tags: ios, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I have an idea to develop an iOS app for indoor locationing. I searched for SDKs and I found I need iBeacons to do so. But It's too expensive. Is there any way to do indoor locationing without iBeacons is iOS?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I will say that there are beacons compatible with Apple's iBeacon program available for $5 per beacon.  That doesn't seem to expensive to test.  If you need hundreds, then perhaps it is too expensive though.  And since that Gimbal beacon I refer to uses batteries, you need to purchase and replace those as well.  The batteries are ~$1.